# Spring file upload with custom message

Tags: spring, file-upload

Using Spring 3.07
I have this upload form which is pretty much the basic spring example for such. Now it displays a message "No file selected" which is correct. However, I don't want this message. My users expect a message in a different language if at all. Does anybody know how I can get rid of this message?

Comment: OMG, how could we know it without your implementation...

Comment: Because this really is the basic spring example from the documentation. If you don't know it you can't help me.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Spring. That message is a browser message for input type file. Mock and scorn reigns down upon me.